# Why can't I remove the empty directory with username www-data?

Tags: permissions, directory, rm

The test is a directory which contains nothing, an empty directory.

```
root@localhost:~# ls -l  /home
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data    4096 Apr 26 17:50 test

root@localhost:~# ls  -l  /home/test
total 0
```

Now I change the username from root into www-data.

```
root@localhost:~# su  www-data
$ rm  -rf  /home/test
rm: cannot remove `/home/test': Permission denied
$
```

Why can't I remove the blank directory `test` which belongs to www-data ?
It can be removed when I login in as root.

```
root@localhost:~# rm  -rf  /home/test

root@localhost:~# ls -lZ /home/test
total 0
root@localhost:~# getfacl /home/test/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/test/
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx

root@localhost:~# ls -al  /home
total 8352
drwxr-xr-x 10 root     root        4096 Apr 26 17:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root     root        4096 Mar 20 16:32 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data    4096 Apr 26 17:50 test
root@localhost:~# ls -al  /home/test
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 26 17:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root     root     4096 Apr 26 17:50 ..
root@localhost:~#
```

Comment: Just in case it's an SELinux issue: please run `getenforce` and `ls -lZ /home/test` for us? Oh, and `getfacl /home/test/`, to be on the complete side.

Comment: What does `ls -al` (instead of `ls -l`) show you? It is possible that there's still one or more  hidden files OR folders inside `/home/test` (starting with a dot (`.`)) which need(s) root permissions to be deleted and which might inhibit the recursive deletion of the entire folder.

Answer (score 10):

You need write permission in the parent direct ory to delete anything from it. In your case this is `/home`, and as only root has write permissions here only root can delete items from it.